# Why does make recompile all files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My goal is the following: I have a directory `src` which contains markdown files (`.md`). I want to run a command on each of these files so that the comments are removed and the edited files are stored in a separate directory. For this I want to use `make`.

This is the `Makefile` I have:

```
.PHONY: clean all

BUILD_DIR := build
SRC_DIRS := src

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.md)
DSTS := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIRS)/%.md,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.md,$(SRCS))

all: $(DSTS)

# The aim of this is to remove all my comments from the final documents
$(DSTS): $(SRCS)
    pandoc --strip-comments -f markdown -i $< -t markdown -o $@

clean:
    rm $(BUILD_DIR)/*.md
```

While this works in general, I noticed that the command is executed on all files, even though I changed only one single file.

**Example:** I have 3 Files `src/a.md`, `src/b.md` and `src/c.md`. Now I run `make` and all files are correctly generated in the `build` folder. Now I only edit `c.md` and run `make` again. I would expect that `make` only "compiles" `src/c.md` anew but instead all three files are compiled again. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
$(DSTS): $(SRCS)
```

is saying ‘All of the DSTS depend on *all* of the SRCS’, so whenever any one of the `$(SRCS)` is newer than any of the `$(DSTS)`, this `pandoc` action will be run.

That's not what you want to express.  What you want is something more like

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.md: $(SRC_DIRS)/%.md
    pandoc --strip-comments -f markdown -i $< -t markdown -o $@

all: $(DSTS)
```

That says that all of the `$(DSTS)` should be up to date, and the pattern rule teaches Make what each one depends on, and how to build it, if it is out of date.

(As a general point, looking your original rule, it's rarely the right thing to do to have multiple targets in a rule, as you have with `$(DSTS)`; also note that in your original, `$<` always refers only to the *first* of the dependencies in `$(SRCS)`)

Comment: You are almost right: _whenever any one of the $(SRCS) is newer than any of the $(DSTS), this pandoc action will be run, once (ie, not once for each input)_ is not correct.  For explicit rules, which the original is, `foo bar : baz` is identical to writing two rules: `foo : baz` and `bar : baz`.  So, `pandoc` will be run once per generated file BUT the expansion of `$<` will always be the same thing since the prerequisites are always the same set of files.  Basically you're stripping the same input file N times and writing it to the N different output files.

Comment: @MadScientist Heavens, you're right: thanks!  I didn't confirm the multiple-target behaviour before writing, but in my defence having multiple targets on the LHS of the colon is in my experience rare enough that I'm not even going to try to remember the logic here!  What you add about `$<` is true – I decided to omit mention of that in the original version because it potentially complicated things, but I've now edited the answer to add a final remark about that, too.